# Iterator value differs from reverse iterator value after conversion

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        v.push_back(i);

    auto it = v.begin() + 3;

    cout << "Iterator: " << *it << endl;

    vector<int>::reverse_iterator revIt(it);

    cout << "Reverse iterator: " << *revIt << endl;

}
```

After running this code I get the following output:

```
Iterator: 3
Reverse iterator: 2
```

Could someone explain why the 2 values differ ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the forward iterator would look forward, whereas the reverse iterator would look back. `v = {1, 2, * 3, 4...}` where * is the iterator position of both of them. Look at which direction they're going.

Comment: @chris: not exactly: or better, this is how java defines iterators (pointing "in between") C++ has a different concept. But the practical result is also in accordance to your explanation. But is a consequence, not the definition.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia, thanks for clearing it up. It wasn't something I'm very familiar with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reverse iterators 'correspond' to a `base` iterator with an offset of one element because  of how `rbegin()` and `rend()` have to be represented using base iterators that are valid (`end()` and `begin()` respectively).  For example, `rend()` cannot be represented by an interator that 'points' before the container's `begin()` iterator, although that's what it logically represents.  So `rend()`'s 'base iterator' is `begin()`. Therefore, `rbegin()`'s base iterator becomes `end()`.
A reverse iterator automatically adjusts for that offset when it is dereferenced (using the `*` or `->` operators).

An old [article by Scott Meyers](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401406) explains the relationship in detail along with a nice picture:

> **Guideline 3: Understand How to Use a reverse_iterator’s Base iterator**
>
> Invoking the base member function on a reverse_iterator yields the
>   “corresponding” iterator, but it’s not really clear what that means.
>   As an example, take a look at this code, which puts the numbers 1-5 in
>   a vector, sets a reverse_iterator to point to the 3, and sets an
>   iterator to the reverse_iterator’s base:
>
> ```
> vector<int> v;
>
> // put 1-5 in the vector
> for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
>   v.push_back(i);
> }
>
> // make ri point to the 3
> vector<int>::reverse_iterator ri =
>   find(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 3);
>
> // make i the same as ri's base
> vector<int>::iterator i(ri.base());
> ```
>
> After executing this code, things can be thought of as looking like
>   this:
>
> [image]
>
> This picture is nice, displaying the characteristic offset of a
>   reverse_iterator and its corresponding base iterator that mimics the
>   offset of rbegin() and rend() with respect to begin() and end(), but
>   it doesn’t tell you everything you need to know. In particular, it
>   doesn’t explain how to use i to perform operations you’d like to
>   perform on ri.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/reverse_iterator/) says they do that to handle past-the-end elements, i.e. if you reverse an iterator that is past the end, the new reverse iterator points to the last element.

Answer (score 2):

The first paragraph of 24.5.1 Reverse iterators says:

> Class template reverse_iterator is an iterator adaptor that iterates from the end of the sequence defined by its underlying iterator to the beginning of that sequence. The fundamental relation between a reverse iterator and its corresponding iterator i is established by the identity:
>   `&*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i - 1)`.

The value returned by `rend()` cannot point before `begin()`, because that is not valid. So it was decided that `rend()` should contain the value of `begin()` and all other reverse iterators be shifted one position further. The `operator*` compensates for this and accesses the correct element anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse iterator looks always "one before" then the forward, since its range is shifted by one:

Forward iterator goes from begin() (the first element) to end() (past the last: [begin-end) is opened at the end side)

Reverse iterator goes from `rbegin() { return reverse_iterator(end()); }` to `rend() { return reverse_iterator(begin()); }` by definition, but also has to walk the open range [rbegin-rend) having rbegin to be the last (not "past the last") and rend to be "before the first" (not "the first") hence a 1 difference to be accommodated.