# C++ deque iterate to second last element

Tags: c++

I am trying to iterate through a deque up to excluding the last entry. Ideally I would avoid counting and comparing to the length, so I tried

```
    auto it_end = dq.rbegin(); it_end++;
    for ( auto it = dq.begin(); it !=it_end; ) {
        if ( cond() ) {
            it = dq.erase( it );
        } else {
            it++;
        }
    }
```

But the compiler complains there is no match operand which seems understandable since I have a reverse iterator and a regular iterator. Is there an elegant way to stop before the last element that avoids counting? Like, an offset?
I also tried usign back, but that turned out to be a reference not an iterator, so != is not happy either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `dq.end() - 1` to get one before the end.

You can also use `std::remove` or `std::remove_if` to remove the items you want instead of doing the job on your own. Note that this is basically kind of like a partitioning operation--it returns an iterator, and everything you want to keep is from the beginning of the range to that iterator. Everything you want to delete is after that iterator, to the end of the range you provided as input.

In this case, you might do something on this general order:

```
std::deque<int> vals { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

// get an iterator one before the end of `vals`
auto end = vals.end()-1;

// remove the even items in the range (so all except `8`)
auto pos = std::remove_if(vals.begin(), end, 
    [](int v){ return v %2 == 0;} 
);

// erase the items we just "removed"
vals.erase(pos, end);

// show the result
for (v : vals)
    std::cout << v << ", ";
```

Comment: Nice. That is as about as simple a solution as one would with it to be. perfect

Comment: Just to be clear, `vals.back() == *(vals.end()-1)`

Answer (score 1):

From **`std::deque::erase`**:

> All iterators and references are invalidated, unless the erased elements are at the end or the beginning of the container, in which case only the iterators and references to the erased elements are invalidated.

Which means, that you cannot iterate over a deque using iterators and delete some elements. Instead, use `std::remove_if` with `std::deque::erase`.

(Untested, but you'll get an idea)

```
std::deque<T> dq = /* ... */;
auto from = std::remove_if(dq.begin(), std::prev(dq.end()),
    [](decltype(dq)::const_reference, decltype(dq)::const_reference){ return cond(); }
);
dq.erase(from, std::prev(dq.end()));
```

Comment: This is why I have it =  dq.erase( it ) From the docs: An iterator pointing to the new location of the element that followed the last element erased by the function call. This is the container end if the operation erased the last element in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
deque dq;
//fill it
for(int i = 0; i < dq.size() - 1; i++) //notice the "-1" to avoid reaching the last element
{
    if ( cond() ) 
    {
        dq.erase(dq.begin()+i);
        i--;
    } 
}
```

You can access `deque` elements with `operator[]`, so `dq[i]` is element number `i` of the deque.

Answer (score 0):

Use `it_end.base()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    deque<int> dq = { 0, 1, 2, 3,4, 5 };
    auto it_end = dq.rbegin(); it_end++;

    for (auto it = dq.begin(); it != it_end.base(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }

    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10373912/12711 for some details on how the `base()` function works for reverse iterators.